# What is role of parser(POS, TAG, Dependecency) in machine translation?

Tags: parsing, deep-learning

I would like to know what is the main purpose of parsing a sentence for example we get all the POS-tag of the sentence in training machine translation? I thought we just need to tokenize the sentence and then feed it into neural network to train? What is the purpose of having the POS tag and how can it be implemented in code for training the model for machine translation?

I cant seem to find any examples. Please assist

Answer (score 1):

If you have a only tokenized word by splitting sentence, you get only dictionary by word.

For example, you have two sentences , [I love coffee], [I like milk].

Dictionary might be [I], [love], [coffee], [like], [milk] called bag-of-word consisted of 5 dimension.

Imagine you make your language only in a dictionary by bag-of-word.
How many dimension do you need for your language?

It would be too big dimensional.

In this circumstance, if you make a language model with POS-tag, you could reduce dimensionality.

[image]

pic 1. you need 9 dimension for representing 9 words.

[image]

pic2. you need only [3,2]-dimension for representing 9 words.

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your explanation. I think I kind of understand it but if possible, could you show me some codes to see the difference? If possible, a simple ones. Thank you